# How to get questions listed with two tags?

Tags: support, search

I am looking for questions based on tags using the tab button. I wish that if there is a way to select two tags and search so that I am eliminate many other questions which I am not so interested in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do a search for both tags, using the search field:

```
[tag1] [tag2]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to search the questions using two tags, you can use (for example) [[drupal] [drupal-7]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal+drupal-7); if you want to look for the questions using one of two tags, you can use (for example) [[drupal] or [drupal-7]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal+or+drupal-7); if you want to search for questions containing a tag but not another,
you can use (for example) [[drupal] -[drupal-7]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal+-drupal-7).
Using both conditions have some *collateral effect*: [[drupal] or [drupal-7] -[drupal-views]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal+or+drupal-7+-drupal-views) returns also those questions containing all the tags.

[image: screenshots]